# Should I upvote well-written questions in technologies I know nothing about?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, voting, triage

I was reviewing a question in [Triage](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage) and it "looked OK."

After pressing "Looks OK," I was shown this message:

> Thanks! The consensus is: this post Looks OK.
>
> Please remember to **upvote** clear, useful, well-researched questions to
>   encourage their authors and help answerers identify them!

<sup>(emphasis added)</sup>

Now the question is about technologies that I don't know about, but I can see that it's a well-written question, since:

- They showed what they have done (not a homework)
- They told us the result they've got (error, or unexpected result)
- They told us the result they expected
- The question is in a good state (formatting, grammar, etc...)

This motivates me to upvote the question, but my concern is that, since I don't know the technologies in which the question was asked, it might be a duplicate.

Should I just leave it, or is it advisable to upvote it?

Comment: Upvoting a duplicate is OK as long as the question shows research effort and the solution isn't obvious or looks searchable at first glance. Duplicates serve as useful signposts to the original question or discussion. Now, we're hypothesising over something that may or may not be true. Leave the debate to someone who actually knows what they're doing. I'd suggest upvoting if you want to, and moving on.

Comment: My personal rule is that I tend to refrain from voting on *answers* when I have no technical competence in the area, and therefore don't feel qualified to judge their quality. I have no such rule for questions. **A good question is a good question. It's obvious.** You don't need any special domain knowledge to judge that. If the question meets all the criteria you list, and *especially* if you think it's an interesting or useful question (votes are limited, so you can't just vote up all questions that meet our guidelines), then definitely feel free to upvote it.

Comment: Duplicates aren't necessarily *bad* anyway, not in the sense that there's anything wrong with upvoting them, or that you should downvote them. Low-quality questions should always be downvoted, and many duplicates are, but that's irrespective of the fact that they're duplicates. Some duplicates are quite useful, as they serve as signposts to the "main" question. If you're knowledgeable  about the subject, looking for duplicates is a good way of helping to keep the site clean. If you're not, then judging the question as you are on its content and presentation is perfectly adequate.

Comment: Things are so bad that I upvote any question that demonstrates a reasonable attempt at testing and debugging:(